# fatal error: linux/proc_ns.h: No such file

Tags: compiler-errors, fedora

I'm trying to compile a project on a fresh Fedora 19 install. I already installed the kernel-devel, kernel-headers, Development Tools and Development Libraries packages. I've confirmed I can compile a simple hello world module, but when compile some drivers, I get the below compilation error:

fatal error: linux/proc_ns.h: No such file

I do not have any issues compiling this on another machine I have Ubuntu installed on. Could I be missing a package on my Fedora system?

Comment: FYI, Fedora 19 has gone EOL.  Did you follow ["Building Only Kernel Modules (Out of Tree Modules)"](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel#Building_Only_Kernel_Modules_.28Out_Of_Tree_Modules.29) from the Fedora custom kernel doc?

Comment: Yes. I'm currently running 3.9.5. To install the kernel-devel and kernel-header packages, I did this: "yum install kernel-devel-3.9.5-301.fc19" and "yum install kernel-headers-3.9.5-301.fc19". Am I missing something else? proc_ns.h is still not in the /usr/src/kernels/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64/include/linux directory.

Comment: I updated to 3.14 and everything is fine now. - Thanks.